# Using cassandra instead of memcache?

Tags: mysql, performance, memcached, cassandra

I keep reeding those articles from different sources that big sites are switching from memcache to cassandra. Coming from a mySQL background, I'll get a slight headache trying to see the pros/cons when compared to each other.

Can you help me out to learn more about this?

Comment: Cassandra is a distributed database. Memcached is a distributed memory object caching system. What are you looking to use it for? caching?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It would be silly to replace memcached *as a cache* with Cassandra in most situations.

What companies like Digg are doing is, replacing the database+memcached pair with Cassandra: Cassandra provides both durable storage, and an integrated, high performance cache (the "row cache").  This prevents problems like memcached being populated from an out of date slave (what Twitter calls "potential consistency") and simplifies cluster management.